# Prove there exist $b$ such that $f(x) = ax +b$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Sorry for maybe duplicate but I searched a lot in this website but can't find any answer for my question:
**Without** using integrals and stuff
consider $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and there is some $a\in \mathbb{R}$, $\forall x\:,\:f'\left(x\right)\:=\:a\:\:$.
Prove that **exist** some $b$ such that $$\forall x,\:f\left(x\right)\:=\:ax+b$$

It seems very trivial but i don't know how to write the proof.
What exactly i need to show? any ideas would be very helpfull.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use definition: $a = f'(x) = lim_{h->0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way (assuming the right things, certainly), is to define

$$h(x):=f(x)-ax\implies h'(x)=f'(x)-a=a-a=0\implies h(x)=b\,(\text{a constant})=\;\forall\,x$$

The above assume that we know $\;f'(x)=0\;$ over an interval $\;\implies f(x)\;$ is a constant there.

Comment: Which comes from the Mean Value Theorem.